# EFCore: What to do when fk constraint failed during SaveChanges() because of non-existant fk object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core

How should I handle non-existant relations?

I am syncing data from an API, and am receiving some bad data:

- A has children B (B has a FK to A)
- I receive a dto B that has an AId but this A does not exist in the set of A dtos.

So, I create the A Entities, and then while creating B entities in EFCore, it uses a shadow property to set the relation to A automatically from the dto when using `Entry.PropertyValues.SetValues(dto)`. At the end of this when calling SaveChanges() I get an `SQLite 19 Foreign Key Constraint Failed` exception because of the non-existant A.

My generic add code

```
//Setup the DBContext...

var newT = new T();
var entry = context.Add(newT);
entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(TDto); //It automatically sets the AId here while adding B entities
```

I'm not sure what my best option is here.

- I could check that A exists during the creation of B, but this is only a simple example and in my actual situation there are many relations like this that would need to be checked.
- Am I going about adding new entities completely wrong? It would be nice to have a generic add method, perhaps I need some kind of callback for custom checks on each entity type?

I can't guarantee that the data coming from the API will be safe.

Dtos

```
public class ADto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
public class BDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid AId { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Classes

```
public class A
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection<B> children { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid AId { get; set; }
    public virtual A { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you could try doing some validation on the data before saving it?

Comment: @JohnB I would have to validate every single relationship coming from the dto. It's painful, but I agree that this is probably my best option.